# Pointer arrays, stopped running

Tags: c, pointers, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Why does this give stopped running after compiling. It gives the output correctly but right after that it corrupts.

```
    #include <stdio.h>


    int main() {

        char *cities[] = {"Adiyaman","Kayseri","Istanbul"};

        int i;

        for(i=0; *(cities+i) != NULL; i++) {

            printf("%s\n",*(cities+i));

        }

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the array the following way

```
   char *cities[] = { "Adiyaman","Kayseri","Istanbul", NULL };
```

Otherwise the loop will not work because the array does not have an element that is equal to NULL.

It would be simpler to write the loop the following way

```
  for ( i = 0; i != sizeof( cities ) / sizeof( *cities ); i++) {

        puts( cities[i] );

    }
```

Or if you want to use pointers then

```
  for ( char **p = cities; p != cities + sizeof( cities ) / sizeof( *cities ); p++) {

        puts( *p );

    }
```

Comment: Yes, I've done the same and it works. It just seemed awkward so that I seeked for another solution for that.

Comment: 'sizeof' doesn't need parentheses in this instance!

Comment: @Skizz If the language allows to write something it does not mean that you should write  it.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: that's a strange argument, 'sizeof avariable' is perfectly readable. It's similar to the 'return' statement, that doesn't need parentheses either but you can add them.

Comment: @Skizz I cannot agree. It is difficult to see the bounds of the expression.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: if it helps then go ahead, I've no problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that the one past last element will be NULL for the `cities` array. It can very well be not-NULL **and** it will be unintended memory access, for sure.

So, by saying

```
for(i=0; *(cities+i) != NULL; i++)
```

you're trying to access an invalid memory (when you have run of of the valid memory locations already) which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You may want to make the NULL as sentinel value by making that the last element of the brace-enclosed initializer list. Something like

```
char *cities[] = {"Adiyaman","Kayseri","Istanbul", NULL}; //explicit NULL
```

Comment: How can I do it without defining the size of the array then?

Answer (score 0):

Please Check     char *name[]={"Bangladesh","Srilanka","Pakistan","India",NULL};